# Editing the same file from multiple computers

Tags: windows-7, linux, text-editing, multiple-users

My friend and I need to view and edit the same file at the same time. We were using Google Docs, but the firewall is now blocking it.

If we connected our computers with a network cable (no hub or routers), could we set up something like Google Docs ourselves? How? Would we need a special program for that?

We both have Windows 7 and Linux (I have Mint, he has Ubuntu), so a solution for either OS would be great.

Comment: The type of file is important.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it's a text file (.doc,.docx or something like that, we can swich)

Comment: A "text file" is a bit different from a "file with text in it".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using SVN, or GIT. It won't let you see edits in real time. However depending on the application you are using and the file type it might suit your needs.

I would use [tortoisesvn](http://tortoisesvn.net/) on windows. It has a diff app for text files and a hook for Word files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft Office 2010 installed on the Windows machines, you can use co-authoring to edit the same document simultaneously. For cross-platform editing and for textural documents, using a source control management system like git or svn (like @NitroxDM suggests), seems like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your simplest solution, since Google Docs was working fine before, is not to find a new app, but to make it so that your firewall doesn't block Google Docs anymore. It should be pretty straightforward to do with simple exceptions.

If not, really... I've heard of Moonedit, which works over the Internet, I think. You could try that out. You can also do that with SVN or a similar software. There are also things like Dropbox shared folders, but those don't update files live, I think.

Comment: thanks. I can't change the settings of the firewall because the firewall is not on my computer but on the gateway I connect through at work.

Comment: Perhaps explain the situation to whoever is responsible for this and try to be allowed to change the settings?

Answer (score 0):

See if [Wikipedia's list of Collaborative real-time editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_real-time_editor) works for you

Comment: explain what the links contain, we dont want the link to be dead at some point in future and your answer rendered useless

Comment: I just did. It shouldn't disappear too soon (wikipedia) and will be kept updated..

Answer (score -1):

I just came across [Pirate Pad](https://web.archive.org/web/20190306131926/http://piratepad.net/front-page/)! It will do exactly what you want. It's not a local application, so you might still have access issues. Good luck.

Comment: The link is dead. So is the software dead as well? I see there is something called [etherpad](https://etherpad.org); is this the same software?